# Revealing module pattern isn't setting my private variable, why?

Tags: javascript, scope

```
function stapler() {

    var color = "black";

    function setColor(newColor) {
        console.log(color); //2. - black
        color = newColor;
        console.log(color); //3. - brown
    }

    function displayColor() {
        console.log(color);
    }

    return {
        c: color,

        set: setColor,

        display: displayColor
    }
}

thing = stapler();

console.log(thing.c); //1. - black
thing.set('brown');
console.log(thing.c); //4. - black, why doesn't this print brown?
```

As you can see from the above, thing.c (the last line) is returning black, but why not brown? Why doesn't the change get saved? What am I missing?

EDIT:

See http://repl.it/7gs for a working copy of the below code.

```
function stapler() {

    var color = "black";

    function setColor(newColor) {
        console.log(color); //2. - black
        color = newColor;
        console.log(color); //3. - brown
    }

    function getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    return {
        get: getColor(),

        set: setColor,
    }

}

thing = stapler();

console.log(thing.get); //1. - black
thing.set('brown');
console.log(thing.get); //4. - black, why isn't this brown?
```

And finally, to really complicate this ... check out the following example -

(viewable at http://replit.com/7hD)

```
function stapler() {

    var color = "black";

    function setColor(newColor) {
        console.log(color); //2. - black, 6. - brown, why now has it changed?
        color = newColor;
        console.log(color); //3. - brown, 7. - purple
    }

    function getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    return {
        get: getColor(),

        set2: function(newColor) {
            setColor(newColor);
        },

        set: setColor,
    }

}

thing = stapler();

console.log(thing.get); //1. - black
thing.set('brown');
console.log(thing.get); //4. - black, why isn't this brown?
console.log(thing.get); //5. - black, why isn't this brown

console.log('-----');

thing.set2('purple');
console.log(thing.get); //8. - black
```

What is going on here?

Comment: you are assigning `c` only once and not using an accessor.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a getter - `return {c:color/*...*/` is putting a copy of the color into that variable the first time, but it's not directly linked to the memory.  Any changes to the private `color` variable isn't linked to the `c` element (which is actually good - if it worked this way you could change the color externally with `thing.c='magenta';`)  Instead you need:

```
function getColor() {return color; }
/*...*/
return { get: getColor, set: setColor, display: displayColor };
```

Comment: I changed it per your advice and it still isn't working. See updated example at http://repl.it/7gs

Comment: You shouldn't have brackets on `return{get: getColor` (by adding brackets you're asking the JS to execute the function and set `get` to the result - not point to the function)

Comment: Is it possible to call get without parenthesis? To treat it more like an attribute?

Comment: Yes... you can consider the parenthesis deferred until call time: your `console.log` lines should rather be `console.log(thing.get());`

Answer (score -1):

Change two lines of your code to

```
function stapler() {

  var color = "black";

  function setColor(newColor) {
    console.log(color); //2. - black
    // color = newColor; CHANGE TO
    this.color = newColor;
    console.log(color); //3. - brown
  }

  function displayColor() {
    //console.log(color); CHANGE TO
    console.log(this.color);
  }

  return {
    c: color,

    set: setColor,

    display: displayColor
  }
}
```

and you'll be fine.

Now, of course, this is no longer the Revealing Module Pattern because you're using "this", but [the Revealing Module Pattern is an anti-pattern](http://slides.com/i-linkuo/the-revealing-module-is-an-anti-pattern#/) anyways, IMHO.